# How to describe a translation of a holy scripture?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which one sounds better?

1. It is an English translated copy of Torah.
2. It is a copy of Torah translated English.
3. It is a copy of Torah translated in English.

Comment: According to the so-called rules of English, aside from the lack of *the* in front of *Torah*, there is nothing actually *wrong* with your first sentence. However, it's a very uncommon construction, and not one that most people would use. Purely comparatively, your first sentence sounds *better*. But I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above are correct.

I believe it should say either:

> It is a copy of the Torah, translated **into** English.

**or**

> It is an English translation of the Torah.

The reason "*translated in English*" is not correct is because translation is a process of moving text from one language to another. The preposition "in" only shows a location or situation, not a direction. Aside from being grammatically incorrect, it would not indicate whether the translation was *from* Hebrew into English or vice-versa.

A more verbose way of expressing that detail would be:

> It is a copy of the Torah, translated from the original Hebrew into English.

Comment: The first would be fine with the definite article and, stylistically, a hyphen after *English*. This can be said: *It is a translated copy of the Torah*. Therefore, this should also be able to be said: *It is an English-translated copy of the Torah.* It's a bit unusual, but not wrong.

Comment: Note @Astralbee's use of the article "the" is paired with "Torah." When speaking to a non-Jewish audience, "the Torah" is our preference. If you are speaking (or writing) to a Jewish audience "Torah" is the preference.

Comment: @JasonBassford Have to say I think your suggestion *is* wrong. Take "English-translated" in isolation - what does that even mean? "Translated" is the past tense of the *process* of translation, and that needs a direction. Was it translated *into* English or *from* English? When you say "an English translation" you are using the word "translation" as a noun for the resulting text itself and describing it as being in English. "English-translated" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Does *it* ***is*** *a translated copy* make sense? Note the present tense. And the fact that *translated* is being used adjectivally, rather than as a verb. Then consider, *It* ***is*** *a half-eaten apple*. The apple ***is*** *half-eaten*. *Half* is an attributive noun applied to the present-tense adjective *eaten*. *It* ***is*** *a half-eaten apple* has the identical syntactical structure as *it* ***is*** *an English-translated copy*.

Comment: @JasonBassford That isn't really the same thing. The past tense of the *process* of "eating" is "ate". You don't say "a half ate apple". "Eaten" is an adjective.

Comment: @Astralbee Then please explain why we can say ***a*** *translated copy*. *Translated* is also being used as an adjective, here to modify the noun *copy*. (Otherwise, you couldn't put an article in front of it.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Because if there is no need to state which language it came *from* or is in now then it makes sense. It is translated. It was once in another language. How about this one - most people say that a transgender woman is a woman. What would a "*transitioning*" woman be? "Transitioning" is a process of moving from one to the other. Are they a woman becoming a man or a man becoming a woman? It's ambiguous. So is "An English-translated copy". Two languages were involved during the translation. It changed from one to the other. Which is it now?

Comment: @Jason https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=English+translation%2C+English+translated%2C+English-translated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEnglish%20translation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEnglish%20translated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEnglish%20-%20translated%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Astralbee So you are rejecting any kind of syntactical analysis and relying purely on what sounds good to you. Your Ngram is the first thing you've said that makes objective sense to me. But at best I think you should say that it is unidiomatic rather than technically wrong. (In the same way that most people hate *irregardless*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry I don't respond to strawman arguments.